# Best way to Authentication Using ASP.NET Web Api and Backbone.js at client side.

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, authentication, backbone.js, asp.net-web-api

i am using ASP.NET, FRAMEWORK 4, M.V.C 4, WEB API. 
I have just started learning ASP.NET web-api and finished CRUD operation in ASP.NET web-api using Backbone.js at client side. now my next task is to build a login, logout and register system.

There are number of ways in asp.net web-api to authenticate user. I just want to know which will be the best way to use in this scenario where Backbone.js will consume ASP.NET web-api in single page application.

Also if any one can tell me any simple tutorial where i can learn asp.net authentication step by step.

Answer (score 3):

You are building SPA then it is recommend to use Token Based Authentication not Cookies, once you obtain the access token from the Auth server (Web API) you need to store it in html5 local storage then with each subsequent request to a protected resource you need to send this access token in the "Authorization" header using bearer scheme.

I've compiled [detailed post](http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/09/angularjs-token-authentication-using-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/) about this but it uses Angular, so it will be very close to backbone.js